# Is FairScheduler applicable to single-node cluster?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-yarn

I am just using my 6GB RAM laptop.
I just want to know if the 'Fair Scheduler' will or can work to single-node cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as there can be multiple mappers and reducers on one node, so the Fair Scheduler will still prioritise.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the cores, that how many JVMs can run. So, I guess you may still be able to test for example of fair scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

It will run - but the effect will be marginal as you can't fit too many tasks in 6GB anyway (don't forget that Hadoop processes themselves also take a nice chunk of this memory).